# Issue in masking XML tag value in java

Tags: java, xml, masking, stringbuffer

I have an XML file shown below:

```
<Envelope>
<Body>
  <user1>
    <userId>userName</userId>
    <password>password</password>
    <creditCard>
        <creditCardNumber>12345678901234</creditCardNumber>
        <cvv>123</cvv>
    </creditCard>
  </user1>
  <user2>
    <userId>userName</userId>
    <password>password</password>
    <creditCard>
        <creditCardNumber>12345678901234</creditCardNumber>
        <cvv>123</cvv>
    </creditCard>
  </user2>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

I have a java code used to log the xml transactions on to some server for future reference. This java code has methods to mask some characters or whole value of tag before logging as the credit card details are not to be disclosed.

Here are the methods:

```
    public static String mask( String input, String[] tags, String maskPattern, String namespacePattern)
        throws Throwable
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( input );
        encodedXML = false;
        if (sb.indexOf( "&gt;" ) > 0) {
            // XML is encoded
            gt = "&gt;";
            lt = "&lt;";
            encodedXML = true;
            // modify patterns for encoded xml
            maskPattern = "(&gt;)" + alphaNumericStuff + "+(&lt;)/";
            if (sb.indexOf( "&quot;" ) >= 0) {
                // There is a mix of double quotes and &quot; in this xml
                namespacePattern = mixedEncodingAlphaNumericStuff + "*";
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            // do a quick check to see if the tag is in the string to reduce excessive string creation
            if (sb.indexOf( tags[i] ) < 0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                sb = maskElementValue( sb, tags[i],maskPattern, namespacePattern );
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }




private static StringBuffer maskElementValue( StringBuffer sb, String tag, String maskPattern,String namespacePattern)
    {
        // Pattern p = Pattern.compile( tag + maskPattern ); doesn't take namespace into account
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile( tag + namespacePattern + maskPattern );
        Matcher m = p.matcher( sb.toString() );
        StringBuffer tempSB = new StringBuffer();
        String namespaceStr = "";
        while (m.find()) {
            namespaceStr = m.group().substring( tag.length(), m.group().indexOf( gt ) );
            // Added full masking for username and password including last 4 characters
            if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase( "username" ) || tag.equalsIgnoreCase( "password" )) {
                m.appendReplacement( tempSB, tag + namespaceStr + gt + xOut( new StringBuffer( m.group().substring( tag.length() + namespaceStr.length() + gt.length() ) ), true ) );
            } else {
                m.appendReplacement( tempSB, tag + namespaceStr + gt + xOut( new StringBuffer( m.group().substring( tag.length() + namespaceStr.length() + gt.length() ) ), false ) );
            }
        }
        m.appendTail( tempSB );
        return tempSB;
    }



private static String xOut( StringBuffer sb, boolean maskAll )
    {
        int dataSize = sb.toString().trim().length() - 1 - lt.length();
        if (!maskAll && dataSize > 4) {
            if (sb.indexOf( "&lt;" ) > 0 || sb.indexOf( "<" ) > 0) {
                StringBuffer tempmaskSB = new StringBuffer( sb.substring( 0, sb.indexOf( "&lt;" ) ) );
                dataSize = tempmaskSB.length();
            }
            // Don't mask last 4 digit
            for (int i = 0; i < dataSize - 4; i++) {
                sb.setCharAt( i, 'X' );
            }
        } else {
            if (sb.indexOf( "&lt;" ) > 0 || sb.indexOf( "<" ) > 0) {
                StringBuffer tempmaskSB = new StringBuffer( sb.substring( 0, sb.indexOf( "&lt;" ) ) );
                dataSize = tempmaskSB.length();
            }
            // Mask all
            for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
                sb.setCharAt( i, 'X' );
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

I am passing the xml as string to the method and an array of tags that are to be masked. If it is username and password they should be masked completely and other tags in the array should be masked except the last 4 characters.

Now the problem is that masking is not happening for some of the transactions. when we have done a load testing, 12 out of 18000 transactions are not masked the protected data.

In some cases, user1 details are getting masked but user2 details are not masked in the same transaction.

Could any one help me in understanding why this is happening? Has anybody faced such issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would *strongly* urge you to stop doing all this string manipulation. To deal with XML, use an XML API. (Also, use `StringBuilder` rather than `StringBuffer` unless you really, really need the synchronization...)

Comment: I'm pretty sure can use a `xslt` & `StAX` in this case.

Comment: Hi Jon, could you please provide some references on how to use XML API.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is helpful. But i would do the masking part with [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)

Example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Mask {
    static String xml =    "<Envelope>\n" +
                "<Body>\n" +
                "  <user1>\n" +
                "    <userId>userName</userId>\n" +
                "    <password>password</password>\n" +
                "    <creditCard>\n" +
                "        <creditCardNumber>12345678901234</creditCardNumber>\n" +
                "        <cvv>123</cvv>\n" +
                "    </creditCard>\n" +
                "  </user1>\n" +
                "  <user2>\n" +
                "    <userId>userName</userId>\n" +
                "    <password>password</password>\n" +
                "    <creditCard>\n" +
                "        <creditCardNumber>12345678901234</creditCardNumber>\n" +
                "        <cvv>123</cvv>\n" +
                "    </creditCard>\n" +
                "  </user2>\n" +
                "</Body>\n" +
                "</Envelope>";
    public static void main (String[]args){
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        Elements toMaskCompletely = doc.select("userId,password");
        Elements toMaskPartially = doc.select("creditCardNumber");
        for(Element ele : toMaskCompletely){
            ele.text("XXXXX");
        }
        for(Element ele : toMaskPartially){
           ele.text("XXXXXXXX"+ele.text().substring(ele.text().length()-4));
        }
        System.out.println(doc.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the version of java we use is 1.4. I doubt JSoup supports java 1.4.